# Multiple instances of UserControl in WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a requirement i.e. one view should have multiple instances at runtime for loading data of different employees from an Xml file  e.g. employee form for creating a new employee details and loading from xml file. I did some search on google and found a very useful link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

For a WPF MVVM application, it is perfect when multiple instances of the ViewModel are created the view reciprocates.  The only problem I see is when I place the text box control with `TabControl` `TabItem` i.e. when I select a particular tab item with in Tab control the other instances of the view reciprocate the same way.  How do I prevent the application from doing this? Is there a property of `TabItem` which could be bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one has similar issue the solution is to bind `SelectedTabGridIndex` to `RadTabItem`.

```
private int _selectedTabGridIndex;
public int SelectedTabGridIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTabGridIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _selectedTabGridIndex)
            return;

        _selectedTabGridIndex = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabGridIndex");
    }
}
```